# I've built a kafka consumer that consumes from a topic with a specified groupId. If I changed the groupID to start from offset 0, it doesn't work

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

In the following method, I'm able to consume many messages from "my_topic". From my understanding, if I want to then start consuming from offset 0 again, I can either

a) Reset the offsets using;

*kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server xxx:9094 --command-config ./xxx --execute --reset-offsets -group my_group -to-earliest*

or...
b) Rename the groupID to something different the "my_group" e.g. "my_group_2".

```
public class MessageConsumer extends ConsumerBase {

  @KafkaListener(topics = "my_topic", groupId = "my_group")
  void processReferralEvents(String message) {
    log.info("message received: [{}]", message);
```

When I do specify my_group_2 as the groupId, then *my_group_2* is created and it automatically assumes the offsets of *my_group*.

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a consumer groupId does not already exist, consumers will use the [auto.offset.reset](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs_auto.offset.reset) setting to find their starting position. This setting defaults to `latest` so it will only consume new records from the topic.

If you set `auto.offset.reset=earliest` and switch to a new groupId then consumers will start from the first available offset (which may not necessarily be 0 if retention policies have deleted the oldest records from the topic)